# NSMutableDictionary automatically converts to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a for loop in objective-c

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *editableDict in myArrayOfDicts)
```

In the loop when I try to add something to the Dict

```
[editableDict setObject:@"peace" forKey:@"soSome"];
```

I am getting a

> -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001a31e0

But why? I thought I set the Dict to mutable at the header of the loop.
Thanks

Comment: The type you put in the for loop declaration is just a hint to the compiler.  If `myArrayOfDicts` doesn't already contain mutable dictionaries then they don't get converted in the loop.

Comment: Just writing `NSMutableDictionary *editableDict` doesn't make it mutable. Reference to objects inside a data structure is immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the actual type inside `myArrayOfDicts` is an `NSDictionary`, try to create a `mutableCopy` before setting an object.

By declaring only `NSMutableDictionary` you are just casting at compile time, but at run time things are different.

Comment: Indeed the actual type is NSDictionary! So the only way to change the Dict in the array would be creating a mutableCopy inside the loop, add the object, remove the NSDictionary from the Array and insert the new NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, pay attention that you can't modify an array (such as removing and adding) in a for loop. Crate a mutable array before the loop, create a mutable copy of the dict inside the loop, change the mutable dict and add it to the new mutable array

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you start with `NSMutableDictionary` instances? Have a look at this example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"obj1" forKey:@"key1"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"obj2" forKey:@"key2"];

NSArray *myArrayOfDicts = @[dict1, dict2];

NSLog(@"%@", myArrayOfDicts);

for (NSMutableDictionary *editableDict in myArrayOfDicts) {
    [editableDict setObject:@"obj2" forKey:@"key2"];
}

NSLog(@"%@", myArrayOfDicts);
```

You can run it yourself, but the results are:

```
(
        {
        key1 = obj1;
    },
        {
        key2 = obj2;
    }
)

(
        {
        key1 = obj1;
        key2 = obj2;
    },
        {
        key2 = obj2;
    }
)
```

See how for `dict2` the value of `key2` is now `obj2`, while the same key-value pair was added to `dict1`.